# .Net Core Angular 2 Jquery decleration

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, webpack

I need to use a jquery function when my angular component is finished generating. I found the the usage below but i couldn't make it work.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
declare var $:any;
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    template: require('./NavMenu.component.html')
})
export class NavMenuComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('selectElem') el: ElementRef;
    public navigation: IMenuItem[];
    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get('http://localhost:52908/api/PageManager/Get?applicationID=3')
            .subscribe(res => this.navigation = res.json().TransactionResult);
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): any {
        $(this.el.nativeElement).find('nav ul').jarvismenu({
            accordion: true,
            speed: true,
            closedSign: '<em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em>',
            openedSign: '<em class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></em>'
        });
    }
}
export interface IMenuItem {
    PageID: number;
    Code: string;
    ApplicationID?: number;
    DisplayText: string;
    IconPath: string;
    ParentID?: number;
    IsFolder: boolean;
    IsDefault: boolean;
    ParentPage?: IMenuItem;
    ChildPages: IMenuItem[];
    BreadCrumb: string;
}
```

When I run this code I get an error that $ is not defined. I tried it with a number variable it gave the same error. Seems I cant declare anything outside class.

I am using webpack too btw.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using jquery in your code?

Comment: Yep i am loading jquery at html. And its workong i have tested it.

Comment: via typescript or via html?

Comment: are you using it in angular ?

Comment: Voa html. Didnt use any jquery in typescript other than here.

Comment: try loading jquery via typescript

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery inside Angular code, it ruins the decoupled nature of angular 2 components. You have now effectively pulled view related code into your component and the component shouldn't be aware of the dom-tree, making your components unable to be unit tested in isolation

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the JQuery code into try catch may help you ,also declare before use of `$`.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): any {
        try{
         $(this.el.nativeElement).find('nav ul').jarvismenu({
            accordion: true,
            speed: true,
            closedSign: '<em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em>',
            openedSign: '<em class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></em>'
        });
       }
       catch(exception){}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use webpack you should tell it to set $ as global variable.
I found this solution:

Install expose-loader.
In your vendor file (or any other that you use for importing jquery) type

```
 import 'expose?jQuery!jquery';
```

In webpack plugins section use ProvidePlugin

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ jQuery: 'jquery', $: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the InjectionToken?
Basically you'll inject the global jQuery instance in your application. Like seen in this post here: [Use jQuery in Angular/Typescript without a type definition](https://thecodegarden.net/jquery-in-angular-typescript-without-type-definition/).

You'll create a **jQueryService.ts** which will define the global instance.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQ_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');

export function jQueryFactory() {
    return window['jQuery'];
}

export const JQUERY_PROVIDER = [
    { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useFactory: jQueryFactory },
];
```

Once you have to you need to import it in your **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

declare let jQuery: Object;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So that you can use it inside your **component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

@Component({
    selector: "selector",
    templateUrl: 'somefile.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor( @Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $: any) { }

    somefunction() {
        this.$('...').doSomething();
    }
}
```